# pandas expand columns after apply function

Tags: python, pandas, database

I have code like that :

```
(base_corr
 .query("date>=@start")
 .groupby(['classe_actifs', 'gestionnaire'])
 ['collecte']
 .sum()
 .unstack('gestionnaire')
 .apply([
     lambda x: x.nlargest(TOP_N).index,
     lambda x: x.nsmallest(TOP_N).index,
     lambda x: x.nlargest(TOP_N).sum()/1_000,
     lambda x: (x.sum() - (x.nlargest(TOP_N).sum() + x.nsmallest(TOP_N).sum()))/1_000,
     lambda x: x.nsmallest(TOP_N).sum()/1_000,
     lambda x: x.sum()/1_000
 ],
     axis=1,
     result_type='expand')
```

it produces :

```
            <lambda>               <lambda> <lambda>    <lambda>    <lambda>    <lambda>
Actions Index(['L. ASSET MANAGEMENT',...    Index(['LF GESTION', 'LBP...    31.6    10.3    -4.1    37.8
Autres  Index(['AASSET MANAGEMENT', 'CR...  Index(['AZZ', ...   5.1 1.8 -0.0    6.9
Cash    Index(['AASSET MANAGEMENT', 'NAINV...   Index(['SON', 'AANVE... 70.0    58.9    -9.5    119.5
Diversifié  Index(['CRMANAGEMENT', ...  Index(['CN', 'ARS F...  15.2    31.9    -7.3    39.9
Obligations Index(['AASSET', 'EAS...    Index(['NAIO... 17.1    14.3    -5.3    26.1
```

I thought that `result_type='expand'` will expand my first 2 columns in different columns but it does not !

any ideas how to do it ?

Comment: what do you mean it isn't in different columns?

Comment: I have in the first columns (called with ```lambda x: x.nlargest(TOP_N).index```) : Index(['L. ASSET MANAGEMENT',...  ie just one column with the TOP_N largest index value